# Neo4j - Performance issues returning all nodes from a path of elements (in a linked-list structure)

Tags: neo4j

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/rO8ybyDPNUA

Was there any resolution to this? I am using Neo4j 2.0 and have a list of about 1300 elements. I am using the Neo4j server and input the following cypher through the browser:

MATCH (p:Project)-[r:Next*0..]->(n) RETURN n LIMIT 1000;

It sits there "Executing query..." for a couple of minutes, and then gives me back "Unknown error".

Also tried:
MATCH (p:Project)-[:Next*]->(n) return collect(distinct n);

With the same result. Going via the REST interface at least I get a result, but it takes minutes. A 1000 node list in my use case is tiny. Is there any work arounds?

By contrast, using:
MATCH (p:Project)-[:Child*]->(n) return collect(distinct n);
Is near instant in returning 1347 nodes, but I don't have ordering/index's on the Child relationships and I don't want them.

Update w/ Profile information:

```
* neo4j-sh (?)$ profile MATCH (p:Project)-[:Next*]->(n) return count(*);
* ==> +----------+
* ==> | count(*) |
* ==> +----------+
* ==> | 1347     |
* ==> +----------+
* ==> 1 row
* ==>
* ==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=[" INTERNAL_AGGREGATE6acd1097-3f62-4f72-b2bb-938f0d8739a1"], returnItemNames=["count(*)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
* ==> EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["( INTERNAL_AGGREGATE6acd1097-3f62-4f72-b2bb-938f0d8739a1,CountStar())"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
* ==>   TraversalMatcher(trail="(p)-[:Next*1..]->(n)", _rows=1347, _db_hits=1347)



* neo4j-sh (?)$ profile MATCH (p:Project)-[:Child*]->(n) return count(*);
* ==> +----------+
* ==> | count(*) |
* ==> +----------+
* ==> | 1347     |
* ==> +----------+
* ==> 1 row
* ==>
* ==> ColumnFilter(symKeys=["INTERNAL_AGGREGATEdb5acb68-6927-4c42-9052-cc1f637f674b"], returnItemNames=["count(*)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
* ==> EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(INTERNAL_AGGREGATEdb5acb68-6927-4c42-9052-cc1f637f674b,CountStar())"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
* ==>   TraversalMatcher(trail="(p)-[:Child*1..]->(n)", _rows=1347, _db_hits=1347)
```

Top one takes minutes, bottom one takes milliseconds.

Comment: Can you show what this returns `MATCH (p:Project)-[:Next*]->(n) return count(*);` counting the total number of paths that are found

Comment: If you can go to the old http://localhost:7474/webadmin, I would also love to see `profile MATCH (p:Project)-[:Next*]->(n) return count(*);`

Comment: I've added the profiling information above.